# FLINK SQL: row.getFieldsAs returns a LocalDateTime instead of a Timestamp?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Flink: 1.13.2

I'm having a StreamTableEnvironment `tableEnv` that read streaming data from a KafkaSource.
From this tableEnv, I filter my data and transform it back to a DataStream.

```java
DataStream<Row> myStreamData = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),"mySource");

tableEnv.createTemporaryView("myTable", myStreamData);
Table mytable = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select source_timestamp, id from mytable");
DataStream<Row> filteredDatastream = tableEnv.toChangelogStream(myTable);
```

> The type for source_timestamp is java.sql.Timestamp and id is String.

Later on, I access my data from `filteredDatastream` and face the issue where `row.getFieldsAs(source_timestamp)` returns a LocalDateTime instead of a Timestamp.

```java
System.out.println(filteredDatastream.getTransformation().getOutputType());
/* 
Out: (
  `source_timestamp` TIMESTAMP(9), // Is a TIMESTAMP 
  `trip_id` STRING
)
*/

filteredDatastream.map(
        row -> {
            System.out.println(row.getFieldAs("source_timestamp").getClass());
            /*
            Out: class java.time.LocalDateTime // (not java.sql.Timestamp)
            */
            return row;
        }
);
```

How can I get `row.getFieldAs("source_timestamp")` to be a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.time.LocalDateTime` without having to cast afterward? Knowing that `java.sql.Timestamp` seems to be handled by flink [data-type-extraction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13//docs/dev/table/types/#data-type-extraction).

Comment: Is there a reason you want `java.sql.Timestamp`? That's a terrible class to use compared to `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: It's because I would like to sink my timestamps on a JDBCSink and inside my JdbcStatementBuilder, I need to cast my `source_timestamp` to java.sql.timestamp

Comment: If you mean that you want to use `setTimestamp()`, you can also use `setObject()` with `LocalDateTime`. So you really don't **need** the `Timestamp`.